# On the distribution of sums of the same random variable.

Tags: probability

Suppose a process generates the random variable, $X$. Now we proceed to generate bundles of $X$ containing $n$ instances of $X$ in each. Having done that, we sum the $X$'s in every bundle, and finally denote these sums $Y$.

Can we say something general about the mean, variance, and perhaps kurtosis of $Y$?

Comment: So your'e saying $Y$ is the sum of $n$ iid random variables distributed as $X$ is, and you want to know the mean, etc, of $Y$?  Is $n$ random? You might want to take a peek at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes my question look silly. If I treat the problem as the sum of $X_1$, $X_2$, ... $X_n$, then the solution is obvious.